# Cross-origin resource sharing error: PreflightInvalidstatus in Azure Application API

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have backend Springboot API service which is running behind the Azure Application Gateway. The APIs are getting used in a Single page application. Spring boot APIs are well configured for CORS and working prefectly fine in ideal scenarios.

But getting CORS errror when Beackendend service is not responsive/down. I setup these values in Application gateway to deal with Preflight calls in case java service is not reachable.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {http_req_Origin}
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, unique-one-time-token
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
```

After doing these rewrite rules , there is still CORS error `Cross-origin resource sharing error: PreflightInvalidstatus`

Answer (score 2):

See if any of the below can be workaround in your case

1. Make sure the request URL in your code isn’t missing a trailing
   **slash**.

   for example, you may need to add a trailing slash  in your
   code— e.g., http://localhost/api/auth/login/   or remove the slash
   if present http://localhost/api/auth/login  and try.
2. This may even happen sometimes when you try calling an **https** service as **http**, for example when you perform a request on :'http:// localhost/api/auth/login ' which might have to be be 'https:// localhost/api/auth/login

Or

3. You need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS
   headers to make this work.

   A CORS-preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if
   the CORS protocol is understood. It uses `OPTIONS`
   as [method](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-method) and includes these  [headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header) .You might need to reply to
   that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers.

**References:**

1. [Fetch Standard (whatwg.org)](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header)
2. [CORS#preflighted_requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests)
3. [CORS](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/)