# Getting CORS error while calling /authorize of Azure Active Directory from Angular Application

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I am getting CORS error when I am trying to call the below API of Azure Active Directory

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={cliendId}&scope=https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code
```

from my Angular application.

This same API works when I paste it in Chrome and hit the enter button, and in response I get the authorization code, but the same doesn't work for Angular. I researched the issue on Google and understood that the issue is because both the domains (client and auth server) are different.
Is there a way I can solve this CORS error?

Additional info:
In Azure Active Directory, I have set Web as the redirect URI, as I was previously getting an error with SPA (please correct me if I have used the wrong redirect URI).
I have also attached a sequence diagram explaining what I need to do with the auth code.
[image: Sequence diagram explaining the communication channel flow]
Thanks in advance!

Edited:
I have added the whole flow of communication channel with figma [image]designs

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to make an HTTP request to /authorize from your front-end. This is not correct. You should make a redirect to /authorize to authenticate the user. If you use MSAL.js, it'll do this for you.

Comment: basically, I need auth code which I will be sending it to the back-end and further process of getting the token will be done by the back-end so can you help me in this; how I can use MASL.js to get the auth code.

Comment: @ShreySoni do you use any library or are you trying to program this by yourself? (you should use a lib). search for msal, open the github page and follow the instructions (that is way to complicated to put here). they also have a wrapper for angular which you might want to use. Also! You have to put your localhost as a redir url in the aad app registration

Comment: @Juunas, can I whitelist the IP in Azure will it work ?

Comment: No, you cannot. I suggest that you check the tutorial for implementing authentication in a front-end SPA: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/blob/main/1-Authentication/1-sign-in/README.md

Answer (score 2):

CORS error usually occurs when the redirect is configured for onr url and routed for other than that.

After following the document ,make sure the request URL in your code isn’t missing a trailing slash.

[image]

for example, you may need to add a trailing slash in your code
ex:`http://localhost/api/auth/login/`  or remove the slash if present or either way for http://localhost/api/auth/login and try.
Also check if you are  using http protocol in place of https.

- for example when you perform a request on :'http:// localhost/api/auth/login ' which might have to be 'https:// localhost/api/auth/login

You need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers to make this work with as  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

For that one need to set  options to call the HTTP request ,

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    Authorization: 'Basic ',// give  authorization method here
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  })
};

getPerson(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(yourbaseurl + '/sdfk/' + name, options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

**Reference** : [Cross-origin resource sharing error: PreflightInvalidstatus in Azure Application API - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862503/cross-origin-resource-sharing-error-preflightinvalidstatus-in-azure-application)

Comment: Yep, I was missing the trailing slash indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you have already resolved this issue or not, but here is what I have faced and resolved later. Hope this helps.

I was also facing the same issue when I was calling the authorize url from angular code, but same url used to work fine when called from web browser.
In my case, BFF redirects the FE to Azure B2C login page.

The mistake I was doing was, I was calling BFF login url as REST API, instead i had to call it like loading a page in angular. Spring boot does require @CrossOrigin(origins = "https://domain") policy defined. But nothing with Azure I needed to do.

In Angular instead of:
*httpClient.get(loginUrl,{headers: headers,responseType:'text'})*

I did:
*window.location = loginUrl*;